# IBM Watson Asistant sys-date system entity does'nt identify "next year march" correctly

Tags: watson-assistant

I have used sys-date entity to identify the date from users input. But the watson assistant sys-date entity doesn't identify some user inputs correctly.
For example: "next year march" is identified as 2020-01-01. 
But if the user input is as "march next year" date is identified as 2020-03-01.

Comment: Have you checked how many sys-dates are returned? It could be that two are detected, e.g., "next year" and "March"

Comment: Yes two are detected. But how can i select the appropriate one when needed. So as "march next year" it is correctly identify the date. But for "next year march" it is not identified.

Comment: What is detected with "next year in March"? What is the confidence for each of the entities?

Answer (score 0):

{
            "entity": "sys-date",
            "location": [
                0,
                9
            ],
            "value": "2020-01-01",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "calendar_type": "GREGORIAN",
                "timezone": "GMT"
            }
        },
        {
            "entity": "sys-date",
            "location": [
                0,
                9
            ],
            "value": "2020-12-31",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "calendar_type": "GREGORIAN",
                "timezone": "GMT"
            }
        },
        {
            "entity": "sys-date",
            "location": [
                10,
                15
            ],
            "value": "2020-03-01",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "calendar_type": "GREGORIAN",
                "timezone": "GMT"
            }
        },
        {
            "entity": "sys-date",
            "location": [
                10,
                15
            ],
            "value": "2020-03-31",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "calendar_type": "GREGORIAN",
                "timezone": "GMT"
            }
        }
This is the entity identification for the input "next year march"